# PDFBox 2.0 : Invisible text from PDFTextStripper

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

File example is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zLzeXFecIp5m8PjsvOQauhn49axshDnV)

I think I need some help from *mkl* again( in attached file there are some hidden () characters which PDFTextStripper extracts. For now I don't see what makes it invisible (for example see column 6 values - all they are in brackets:

Publix Liquors 1,600 2.5 1/1/2014 12/31/2018 ($ 24,000.00) ($ 4,032.00)   ($ 28,032.00)
BayCare Health Systems 3,200 5 7/30/2004 7/31/2018 ($ 51,200.00) ($ 9,648.00)   ($ 60,848.00) No rent change until Option Period 8/11/2018

..............

Could you please at least point why they are hidden *in this case*? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you deal with actual transparency.

The hidden brackets are created by blocks of instructions like this

```
q
/Alpha3 gs
0 0 0 rg
BT
0 Tr
/Font0 14.299999 Tf
1.0 0 0 -1.0 537.66486 195.42578 Tm
0 0 Td
<037F>
Tj
ET
Q
```

The extended graphics state **Alpha3** in the resources is declared as

```
14 0 obj
<<
  /CA 0
  /ca 0
>>
endobj
```

Thus, `/Alpha3 gs` sets both the stroke and the fill opacity to 0, i.e. anything drawn using fill or stroke is completely transparent.

In the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` these values can be retrieved in `processTextPosition` from the current graphic state (`getGraphicsState`) as properties `getAlphaConstant` and `getNonStrokeAlphaConstant`

Comment: Thanks! could you please point some resource where i can learn how to understand those various instructions?

Comment: I learned from the PDF specification (you can retrieve a copy of the ISO 32000-1 standard at Adobe: [PDF32000_2008.pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) and a general interest in text extraction and redaction... i.e. looking at the internals of many PDFs.

Comment: Thank you. There are so many things could hide text in result PDF, so standard PDFTextStripper is almost useless... I'm wondering is there any lib doing all that staff to return only what we see in pdf

Comment: You might be surprised to hear that while there indeed are very many ways to have non-visible text in PDFs, these ways generally are seldom used. The amount of examples you came across is astounding! ;) In many use cases standard text extraction returns the wanted data. More common complaints are that the original layout is not honored, in particular for tabular contents. That being said, in some use cases people even *want to retrieve invisible text*, for them this is not a bug but a feature!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for huge help! Hopefully there is no more such ways remaining :)